# How can I convert cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates using function

Tags: matlab, function

I'm trying to create a function in MATLAB that takes a cartesian coordinate and converts it to polar.

```
function [homework5] = Cartesian(X,Y)

M = size(X,1)

for N=1:M
if X,Y;

r=sqrt(X^2+Y^2)
theta=atan(Y/X)


else
disp('input incorrect')


end   

 if r > 10
    disp('Far from Origin')
else
    disp('Close to Origin')

 end

end
```

I'm extremely new to MATLAB and my searches for the answer and reading tutorials e.t.c have proved futile.

I have it to where it converts 1 coordinate just fine, but I need to convert multiple coordinates at once (hence the forloop) but I can't get it! The user needs to be able to enter an array like this: >>Cartesian = [2,3;4,5;6,7] and have each row converted.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you want to use MATLAB's function [CART2POL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cart2pol.html)?

If you look inside it just do this:

```
th = atan2(y,x);
r = hypot(x,y);
```

---

As for your code, it has many issues with syntax and logic.

First you don't need the loop. MATLAB specifically designed to work with vectors and matrices. You have to use element-wise multiplication, delition and power with `.*`, `./` and `.^` operators.

Also `if X,Y;` doesn't do anything. Read the doc how to use `if` properly. You preallocate `M` but don't use it. The function is supposed to return `homework5`, but it's not defined in the function's body. You have to read about functions. Make sure the function is saved into the file with the same name `Cartesian.m` and in the current directory or in the MATLAB's path.

Comment: Yeah I saw that a while ago but my professor apparently wants the actually equation to be typed out.  I don't see why it makes a difference but that's the way he wants it.

Comment: Maybe your professor wants you to figure out how to convert the coordinates programmatically and not just use some specific function.

Comment: I think you should go on the way you started with: r=sqrt(X^2+Y^2); and theta=atan(Y/X)); but you must pay attention to the points where X is negative. ATAN function only outputs angles from -pi/2 to pi/2 (where X is positive). You should add some 'if' statement to verify if the angle is on the 2 or 3rd quadrant (X<0) and then add 'pi' to the resulting angle if X is negative. (notice that atan(X/Y) will return the same value for X = -1, Y = -2 and for X = 1, Y = 2).

Comment: This specific dubious output of the atan function for coordinate conversion. That's exactly what I think your professor wants you to learn and understand with this exercise...
(you may use atan2 too which does the same thing I explained above but won't make you learn this point).